# Tranferring Large Data Between Servers Fast

Tags: c#, java, windows, networking

This is a common question, but Googling this gives a lot of crap.

As data volumes are getting higher and higher, all along with processing power & cloud capabilities, we are witnessing a growing need for fast data transfer technologies capable of unleashing the power of all this available data by spreading / moving / sharing it across different servers/clients.

In our case, we are recording real time binary data (50 Gigs a day) and we need to upload it / download it every day to/from subscribers (yes, all of it is needed locally by each subscriber server, for computing and various data analysis stuff)

So to put is shortly, **what are choices available today to transfer many Gigs of Data REALLY FAST between remote windows servers** (VPS's, Cloud, with a "fairly" consistent bandwitdth -(optic fiber put aside) )

This is an open question. Every Idea is welcome whatever the protocol.

Comment: i think this might be suited better for programmers?

Comment: How is stored the data ?

Comment: I know CloudOpt, which seems to be an interesting solution (http://www.cloudopt.com/). I am though curious to know what other recent technologies/setups have to offer

Comment: These 'subscriber servers', is there any reason they can't all be on the same LAN, along with your master server? Or are they controlled by the clients?

Comment: Did you consider using the BitTorrent protocol?

Comment: @SteveB Large Binary Files (~1Gig)

Comment: @ThomasMueller : This might be possible... but I don't thing there are enough subscribers to create a significant sufficient torrent leverage (in terms of seeders, leeshers)

Comment: As an option see [Sneakernet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sneakernet)

Comment: a mirroring service that is running all the time will 'hide' a lot of transfer time, as well as giving you multiple points to pull from.

Comment: @lynks : Good question. LAN is the past :-)
Our network is scattered throug different virtual/physical machines We have 10 to 20 different Cloud HPC servers / Dedicated Servers / Local workstations / VPS's. If we had to put this on a LAN it would cost one leg to each developer we have every month. We do not have enought developers/legs for that.

Comment: @MikaJacobi haha xD ahh well, let me live in the past. i have a server cluster (yep; real, metal, boxes) on a gigabit lan, horizontal scaling can bite me :P

Comment: @oleksii LOOOOL XD Actually this is an option that Amazon (AWS) offers to transfer large data files. They literally ask you to send them a portable Hard drive so they can upload your data

Comment: @JaneDoe no, ServerFault

Comment: How about real time distribution? A data distribution service (DDS) may be your solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The challenge of sending and receiving the data over the network is multi-fold.

1. The network bandwidth is the **most limiting factor** and there is hardly anything you can do for this at application level (except occasional compress the data and even in that case the compression ration determines the gain). So faster network is the first choice.
2. Certain protocols are more suited for transferring certain type of files/data. For example http is a text based protocol and and not really suited for binary and large contents. But since its the most popular web protocol which needs binary contents to be sent over the wire, techniques like [encoding and chunking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) have evolved. HTTP **is really not the choice** if your data is in the order of GBs which is your case.
3. **FTP** is the most popular protocol used to transfer files over the network and its specifically designed for transferring files. There are several extension of FTP like [GridFTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GridFTP), [bbftp](http://www.slac.stanford.edu/BFROOT/www/Computing/Offline/DataDist/bbftp-install.html) which are very **specifically designed** for large data transfers.
4. BitTorrents is another option that can be explored. Facebook uses BitTorrents to push the binaries to the servers (tens of thousands in number).

You problem is very open ended and I am limited by my experience :). [Here is link](http://moo.nac.uci.edu/~hjm/HOWTO_move_data.html) I found which deals of large data transfers. Hope this helps you.

Comment: +1 for use of bit torrent or similar peer to peer protocols as you have to send multiple copies and the network bandwidth is likely to be the limiting factor.

Comment: +1 for diverse approach. I would also add [sneakernet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sneakernet). Somehow, people at Serverfault [frown upon](http://serverfault.com/a/332612/82856) ftp for this purpose. Also there are [some other](http://serverfault.com/questions/332606/what-is-the-fastest-and-most-reliable-way-of-transferring-a-lot-of-files) solutions discussed, not sure if those can be used programmatically though.